# Regularity of the Peano form of Taylor's theorem's remainder

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am reading a book and the author claims the following:

Let $f(x,t)$ be smooth, then we can apply Taylor's theorem in $t$ and obtain:

$$f(x,t) = f(x,0)+f'(x,0)t+\frac{f''(x,0)}{2}t^2+h(x,t)t^3$$

where prime denote derivatives in $t$ and $h$ is smooth in $x,t$.

I looked at wikipedia and another similar question posted here 4 years ago, but

1.) The Peano form of the remainder should be multiplied by $t^2$ to obtain the remainder, not $t^3$.
2.) In the other thread, it is only shown that the peano form $h \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow 0^+$, it says nothing about the differentiability of $h$.

Does anyone know how one would prove the statement above?

Comment: Please make it clear that your primes denote (partial) differentiation with respect to $t$; moreover, a factor of $1/2$ is missing on the quadratic term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral form of the remainder term ( cf. Wikipedia) is (aside from a constant $1/k!$ that I'll ignore to simplify typesetting)
$$R_k(x)= \int_{t=0}^{t=x} (x-t)^{k} f^{k+1}(t) dt$$ Hold $x$ fixed. Making the change of variables $t=x s$ we get $$R_k(x)= x^{k+1}\int_{s=0}^{s=1}  (1-s)^k f^{k+1}(x s) ds$$

Note that $h=\int_{s=0}^{s=1}  (1-s)^k f^{k+1}(x s) ds$ is a smooth function of $x$.

In your problem, $f$ also depends on a second parameter, but this formula shows that $h$ is also a smooth function of that parameter.

Comment: Gosh....I was thinking completely in all the wrong and complicated direction, thank you for your help!